# How to toggle bool property

Tags: c#

What's the cleanest way of toggling 4 bools. So if I set Bool2 to true all the others are set to false. Similar to a radio button but with these four properties. Could this be done using Ternary Operator/ logical operators?

XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text=" {Binding Bool1}"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text=" {Binding Bool2}"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text=" {Binding Bool3}"></TextBlock>
<TextBlock Text=" {Binding Bool4}"></TextBlock>
```

C#:

```
bool b1;
public bool Bool1
{
    get { return b1; }
    set
    {
        b1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Bool1));
    }
}

bool b2;
public bool Bool2
{
    get { return b2; }
    set
    {
        b2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Bool2));
    }
}

bool b3;
public bool Bool3
{
    get { return b3; }
    set
    {
        b3 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Bool3));
    }
}

bool b4;
public bool Bool4
{
    get { return b4; }
    set
    {
        b4 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Bool4));
    }
}

void Toggle(object ThePropertySetToTrueHere)
{

}
```

Comment: If only one variable is ever true, then why not store that fact in one variable and store the "id" of the one selected. e.g. `int selected = 3` ?

Comment: use an Enum instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion - an enum

```
 public class WhatEver
 { 
      public enum WhatsTrue{
             Thing1,
             Thing2,
             Thing3,
             Thing4
      };
      WhatsTrue Truth;
      void SetTruth(WhatsTrue truth){
        Truth = truth;
      }
  }
```

Instad of - somewhere in the code going

```
if(Bool1).....
```

or

```
if(!Bool3) ....
```

do

```
 if(Truth == WhatsTrue.Thing1) ..
```

or

```
 if(Truth != WhatsTrue.Thing3)
```

Comment: How do I use it please? how do the others get set to false?(I Have modified the question to show the relationship with the UI- )

Comment: @Decoder94 - you do not have any other bools, see edit